# usb powered speakers connected to little high power output charger

Tags: usb, speakers

Is it okay connect my usb powered speakers to a charger of 1.2 amp? but on site it says that connect them to 5V 1AMP charger, will the speakers get damaged?

Answer (score 0):

You will not damage the speakers by connecting them to a higher output USB power source. The speakers will only draw the current they require. They will not draw more just because there is more available.